# SED: Find patterned lines and update only one

Tags: awk, sed

I have a DNS zone file where **only one** of the NSs record should be updated: either of them should become **dns2.hosting.com**.

```
domain.com.     1800000 IN      SOA     dns1.hosting.com.      cpanel.one.domain2.com.      (
                                            2018101101 ;Serial Number
                                            86400 ;refresh
                                            7200 ;retry
                                            3600000 ;expire
                                            86400   )

domain.com.     1800000 IN      NS      dns1.hosting.com.
domain.com.     1800000 IN      NS      dns1.hosting.com.
```

I tried to use sed to achieve this, it only updates both of records. Please help.

```
sed -i '/NS/ s/dns1/dns2/' domain.com.db
```

Expected result:

```
domain.com.     1800000 IN      SOA     dns1.hosting.com.      cpanel.one.domain2.com.      (
                                            2018101101 ;Serial Number
                                            86400 ;refresh
                                            7200 ;retry
                                            3600000 ;expire
                                            86400   )

domain.com.     1800000 IN      NS      dns1.hosting.com.
domain.com.     1800000 IN      NS      dns2.hosting.com.
```

Comment: With GNU `sed`, use `sed  '0,/NS/ s/dns1/dns2/'`

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew It also updates SOA which is wrong

Comment: @Alexander, Could you please post your expected output and let us know then.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 added

Comment: So you want to replace the last occurrence only?

Comment: @Alexander, Could you please also mention what is the condition of changing string here?

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew  Yes

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 One of the string containing 'NS' should have 'dns1' changed to 'dns2'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -i -e '0,/\<NS\>/s/\(\<NS.*\s\)dns1/\1dns2/' domain.com.db
```

The range `0,/\<NS\>/` limits the search and replace to the lines from the beginning of the file to the first occurrence of `NS` as a separate word. The replacement is done only on the lines matching `\(\<NS.*\s\)dns1`.